# Reading a specific line of a file

Tags: shell, command-line, text

What is the best way (better performance) to read a specific line of a file? Currently, I'm using the following command line:

```
head -line_number file_name | tail -1
```

ps.: preferentially, using shell tools.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `sed`.

```
# print line number 10
$ sed -n '10p' file_name
$ sed '10!d' file_name
$ sed '10q;d' file_name
```

Comment: On my system, your last example is generally faster than the awk, head/tail or ruby versions unless the line is near the end of the file. Only the tail/head version begins to get a little faster as the line approaches the end of the file.

Answer (score 5):

```
#print 10th line
awk NR==10 file_name
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk -v linenum=10 'NR == linenum {print; exit}' file`

Comment: Could just use `awk NR==10 file_name` as in my answer.

Comment: If the file is huge, you don't want to read the rest of it needlessly, so exit.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the lines are the same length, then a program could directly index in to that line without reading all the preceeding ones: something like od might be able to do that, or you could code it up in half a dozen lines in most-any language.  Look for a function called seek() or fseek().

Otherwise, perhaps...

```
tail +N | head -n 1
```

...as this asks tail to skip to the Nth line, and there are less lines put needlessly through the pipe than with your head to tail solution.

Comment: That should be `head 1` instead of `head -1`.

Comment: @Dennis: are you sure? With all the head implementations I've ever seen `head 1` would try to find a file called "1". I've double-checked on GNU/Linux and it's definitely `head -1`. Which version of head do you use?

Comment: Oh, sorry, GNU `head` insists on `-n` so `head -n 1`. I typoed my comment. With a `-n -1` GNU `head` outputs all but the last line rather than just the first. Version: head (GNU coreutils) 7.4

Comment: @DennisWilliamson ahhh... I see GNU docs refer to the old `-1` syntax ala "obsolete option syntax -countoptions" [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html) - will update to `-n 1`.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby -ne '$.==10 and (print; exit)' file
```

Comment: `ruby -ne '$.==10 and (print; exit)'` will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it couple of times to avoid the file cache and found the head + tail was quick but the ruby was the fastest:

```
$ wc -l myfile.txt
920391 myfile.txt

$  time awk NR==334227 myfile.txt
my_searched_line

real    0m14.963s
user    0m1.235s
sys 0m0.126s

$  time head -334227 myfile.txt |tail -1
my_searched_line

real    0m5.524s
user    0m0.569s
sys 0m0.725s

$ time  sed '334227!d' myfile
my_searched_line

real    0m12.565s
user    0m0.814s
sys 0m0.398s

$ time ruby -ne '$.==334227 and (print; exit)' myfile
my_searched_line

real    0m0.750s
user    0m0.568s
sys 0m0.179s
```